# Is there any way to get the Name, Email and phone numbers from the Business card through computer vision API in xamarin.forms

Tags: computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

I am able to get the text in the image through the **Microsoft's Computer vision** API but can I directly get the **Name**, **Email** and **Phone Numbers** classified directly from the API?

If possible how can I do that?

I tried validating the email and phone number using regex but I don't know how to get the Name from the business card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Text Analytics API from Microsoft to get the name as it recognizes a word as person, number and other.

Email and phone numbers were extracted by using regex.